# How to add and remove role from users using ID

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to create a command which allows users with the role `Recruiter` to promote `tryout` to `soldier`, I'm using `arg1` as the mentioned user and then striping that down to get just the ID, but i cant add the roles since it keeps saying `` `str` object has no attriubute `add_roles` ``

```
  @bot.command(name="promote", aliases = ["p"])
  @commands.has_role('Recruiter')
  async def _promote(self , ctx: commands.Context , arg1):
    """Promotes a tryout to recruit"""
    guild = ctx.guild
    tryout = ctx.guild.get_role(976813881232085052)
    soldier = ctx.guild.get_role(973765272106332211)
    userid = arg1.strip("<>@!")
    await userid.add_roles(soldier)
    await userid.remove_roles(tryout)
    await ctx.send("Successfull")
```

Comment: Why are you not using: `user: discord.Member` as an argument instead of `arg1` and making it much more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read about this library [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#basic-converters) and make your life easier;

But in a nutshell typehinting `member: discord.Member` will actually try to convert string you say in discord to `discord.Member` object so for example
`!promote @Alex`, `!promote Alex`, `!promote 1234567` (alex id) will put Alex into `member` argument as `discord.Member` (which can be used for `add/remove_roles`) and raise `commands.MemberNotFound` if none member could be found.

```py
    @bot.command(name="promote", aliases=["p"])
    @commands.has_role('Recruiter')
    async def _promote(self, ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member):
        """Promotes a tryout to recruit"""
        tryout = ctx.guild.get_role(976813881232085052)
        soldier = ctx.guild.get_role(973765272106332211)
        await member.add_roles(soldier)
        await member.remove_roles(tryout)
        await ctx.send("Successfull")
```